# What is a Structurer?

Tags: career

People "on the Street" distinguish between quants and structurers. Who are the structurers? what do they do?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic.  Job and other institutional questions like this are not within the scope.  As an example: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/51/are-questions-about-financial-institutions-on-topic  That being said, you could ask an appropriate question about *structuring*, but you would need to provide context/detail.

Comment: Seconded, this is not a helpful question.

Comment: Then why "What is a Quant" is acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

Structurers are simply guys that actually have something to sell.

They (usually) try to identify if their clients have some complex balance sheet problems, or risks to hedge, or returns to get, and propose them Structured Products" that can fit those problematic.

Regards